# What is wrong in this definition of a newcommand with variable number of parameters in its argument?

Tags: arguments, parameters, variable

I want to define a command to draw schemas of the type shown in the following figure, but for an indeterminate number of branches. The inputs will always be positive integers.

[image]

The numbers of the branches to the right are obtained as a function of the corresponding numbers to the left using the first two parameters, by the following function: #1/{2*#2*\entry}, where \entry is the variable number to the left. The schematic in the figure should be obtainable by running the command with the following inputs:\st{252}{1}{1,2,3,6,7,9}

The error returned by the Latex editor is as follows: ***"File ended while scanning use of @argdef."***

**This is the code I have been testing with:**

```
% #1 = v, #2 = lambda_i, #3 = variable argument {a_1, a_2, ...}
\newcommand{\st}[3]{%
    \newcounter{ni} % crea un contador
    \setcounter{ni}{2} % inicializa el contador ni en 2
    \draw (0 , 0) -- (0, 8);
    \draw [fill=gray!50] (0 , 0) circle(1.6);
    \draw (0, 0) node {{\large \textbf{2}}};
    \foreach \superscript/\entry in {#3} {%
        \draw (-\entry , 2*\entry) -- (\entry, 2*\entry);
        \draw [fill=black] (0, 2*\entry) circle(.2);
        \draw [fill=white] (\entry , 2*\entry) circle(1);
        \draw [fill=white] (-\entry, 2*\entry) circle(1);
        \draw (-ni, 2*ni) node {\entry};
        \draw (ni, 2*ni) node {#1/{2*#2*\entry}};
        \addtocounter{ni}{1} % incremento el contador ni en 1
    }%
    {
```

I'm sorry; I had forgotten the header and footer for Tikz, but the error I am getting is still the same.

This is the new code:

```
% #1 = v, #2 = lambda_i, #3 = variable argument {a_1, a_2, ...}
\newcommand{\st}[3]{%
    \newcounter{\ni} % this creates a counter
    \setcounter{\ni}{2} % this initializes the \ni counter to 2
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, line width=1pt]
        \draw (0 , 0) -- (0, 8);
        \draw [fill=gray!50] (0 , 0) circle(1.6);
        \draw (0, 0) node {{\large \textbf{2}}};
        \foreach \superscript/\entry in {#3} {%
        \draw (-\entry , 2*\entry) -- (\entry, 2*\entry);
        \draw [fill=black] (0, 2*\entry) circle(.2);
        \draw [fill=white] (\entry , 2*\entry) circle(1);
        \draw [fill=white] (-\entry, 2*\entry) circle(1);
        \draw (-\ni, 2*\ni) node {\entry};
        \draw (\ni, 2*\ni) node {#1/{2*#2*\entry}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        \addtocounter{\ni}{1} % increments the counter \ni by 1
    }%
    }
```

---

**The figure that I attach as an example I have obtained with the following code:**

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, line width=1pt]
            \def\x{10};
            \draw (0 , 0) -- (0, 14);
            \draw [fill=gray!50] (0 , 0) circle(1.6);
            \draw (0, 0) node {{\large \textbf{1}}};
            \foreach \x in {2,...,7}
            {
                \draw (-\x , 2*\x) -- (\x, 2*\x);
                \draw [fill=black] (0, 2*\x) circle(.2);
                \draw [fill=white] (\x , 2*\x) circle(1);
                \draw [fill=white] (-\x, 2*\x) circle(1);       
            }
            \draw (-2, 4) node {9};
            \draw (2, 4) node {14};
            \draw (-3, 6) node {7};
            \draw (3, 6) node {18};     
            \draw (-4, 8) node {6};
            \draw (4, 8) node {21};     
            \draw (-5, 10) node {3};
            \draw (5, 10) node {42};        
            \draw (-6, 12) node {2};
            \draw (6, 12) node {63};
            \draw (-7, 14) node {1};
            \draw (7, 14) node {126};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: An error "File ended while scanning use of ..." means that you're missing the delimiter of an argument or a closing brace. In this case, you use an opening brace in your last line that should be a closing brace.

Comment: Yes, Skillmon; quite an obvious mistake ... but not yet solved the problem. There is something else wrong. I have also tried changing the name of the counter variable neither to \ nor. There seem to be some mismatched parentheses, brackets, or braces, but I can't find it.

Comment: note that you are allocating a new counter every time you probably want that `\newcounter` outside the macro. also `\ni` is a standard latex command you should probably pick a different name.

Comment: Try double braces: {{1,2,3,6,7,9}}.  See page 1044 of PGF manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors. In particular, `\foreach \superscript/\entry` requires that the list is in the form `a/b,c/d` and so on.

Also it's better to go bottom up with the list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\st}[3]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, line width=1pt]
        \draw (0 , 0) -- (0, 2*dim{{#3}}+2);
        \draw [fill=gray!50] (0 , 0) circle(1.6);
        \draw (0, 0) node {{\large \textbf{#2}}};
        \foreach \superscript [count=\ni from 2] in {#3} {%
        \draw (-\ni, 2*\ni) -- (\ni, 2*\ni);
        \draw [fill=black] (0, 2*\ni) circle(.2);
        \draw [fill=white] (\ni , 2*\ni) circle(1);
        \draw [fill=white] (-\ni, 2*\ni) circle(1);
        \draw (-\ni, 2*\ni) node {\superscript};
        \draw (\ni, 2*\ni) node {\the\numexpr#1/(2*#2)/\superscript};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\st{252}{1}{9,7,6,3,2,1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, egreg !!!. Many thanks. Perfect solution, with optimized code. I will need a little time to assimilate all the details. A very good idea also to reverse the order of the inputs in the nodes on the left side. I have simply added the centering. I needed to create a good number of these schematics and without the new command, the code was going to be monstrous. Your solution is, simply, perfect. I think this exercise will be useful to many latex users, beginners and not-so beginners ... Best regards from Spain.

Comment: @JesúsÁlvarezLobo You're welcome!